# Magento GST Tax Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I manage whole e commerce multi designer fashion website. today, i create GST Tax Classes as per indian law for different - different products(ex: footwear, carpets, sarees, jewelery, dresses), but i am confusing if somebody place order on website from out of country, GST will applicable or not for international orders?.

Comment: GST applicable only in India, if order placed by another country NO GST.

Comment: One More Issue, when someone placed order from different state how will apply IGST. now i create only SGST, CGST.

Comment: @AtulKumar please accept answer.....

Comment: @AtulKumar for global sales you need to consult with CA, or implement IGST accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**For my knowledge** , GST will apply if some one buy from anywhere, even from another planet ;) jokes apart, if any product sold from site, you will recieve money from customer and for that you need to pay tax for Indian Government.

Feel free to post this question [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/) , you may get better advice.....

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate GST for India as per rules you can calculate based on state. you just need to set business origin state .and based on that you need to fetch customer state in the shipping address.

```
if($customercountry== "IN" && $bussinessoriginstate==$cutomerstate){
calculate SGST(taxrate/2) and CGST(taxrate/2)
}else{
   calculate IGST(taxrate)
}
```

Please let me know if you required more information regarding this.